# mouseover on text html

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my javascript file there is,

```
var htm = '<div style="overflow:hidden;height:24px;width:150px;" onmouseover="tooltip(this)">' ;

function tooltip(sp)
{
    sp.title = sp.innerHTML;
}
```

So on mouse over a text the tooltip is displayed.But the tool tip does not stay longer. meaning the position is not fixed.
Can the code be modified such that mouse over should be done on the text and the tool tip also........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a "built-in" tooltip, there's no need at all to do it dynamically. Just code the HTML element with a "title" attribute containing the text you want. The browser will show the tooltip on mouseover. If you want something fancier, you should probably look at a jQuery add-on (or some other framework).

Comment: if you are not interested to use jQuery/prototypejs only for the tooltip plugin, you can try the following link,

http://amar-desh.net/myworks/javascript/ToolTip_using_javascript.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: How can we add a dynamicaly generated text in the tooltip? Like a different tooltip depending on the date? Im not focussing on the date. Just as an example. Could also be some data fetched from a db query into an html element?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta you can update the "title" property of the element.

Comment: @Pointy Yes right, But say I want something like : 
`hello <planet>` and `planet` could be `earth` `mars` `venus`. Depending on something else. Probably not the correct syntax. But I hope I got my point across to you. :)

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta well there are many ways to concatenate pieces of a string together; in JavaScript it can be as simple as using the `+` operator to build a string out of pieces. Once you've done that, the "title" attribute can be set to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standards based tooltip that will serve you well.

```
<div title="This is your tooltip">Some Text</div>
```

If you then wish to add on top of this, you can use the title attribute to get the text you want to display as a tooltip, which is how various tooltip plugins work.